# Why hasn't the string been replaced when it is from string resource file in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

When I use Code A, I get the original string ,why?

Code B can replace string both `${myObject.status}` and `${myObject.name}`, the result is OK.

**Image**

[image]

**Code A**

```
<string name="DetailsOfWiFiDef">The WiFi status is ${myObject.status},
        the name of WiFi is ${myObject.name}\n\n
</string>

val myObject=getIt()
val s=mContext.getString(R.string.DetailsOfWiFiDef)
val sb = StringBuilder()
sb.append(s)  //The string keep original
```

**Code B**

```
val myObject=getIt()
val k="The WiFi status is ${myObject.status},the name of WiFi is ${myObject.name} \n"
val sb = StringBuilder()
sb.append(k)  //It has been replaced
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin compiler converts string literals into `StringBuilder` chain at compile time:

```
// code in Kotlin
val k = "The WiFi status is ${myObject.status},the name of WiFi is ${myObject.name} \n"

// is converted into equivalent of code in Java
String k = new StringBuilder("The WiFi status is ").append(myObject.getStatus()).append(",the name of WiFi is ").append(myObject.getName()).append(" \n");
```

If you load through resources there's no conversion, it's used as is. However you can use formattable [string resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling):

```
<string name="DetailsOfWiFiDef">The WiFi status is %1$s,
        the name of WiFi is %2$s\n\n
</string>
```

Then inject arguments when reading string (Android Studio even corrects You if you proide too many arguments or wrong type in real time):

```
val s=mContext.getString(R.string.DetailsOfWiFiDef, myObject.status, myObject.name)
```